# Share iOS URL Scheme without browser redirect if app installed

Tags: ios, safari, share, url-scheme

I want to do the same think youtube does with its app.

Share a URL that when the person who receives it opens, it opens the app (without opening safari and then redirect to app) if it is installed, or redirects to the itunes store if it is not installed.

What I managed to do was something like this:
a page in my webserver that constains

```
<script>
  window.location = 'myurlscheme://...;
  setTimeout(function() { window.location = 'https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/my-app/id00...'; }, 1000);
</script>
```

And when the user goes to the link I shared (via message or email) to this page, it opens the link in mobile safari and then it opens the app if it is installed and if it is not, after 1 second it opens the itunes store.

What I want is the same behavior as when you share a link via the youtube iOS app, which opens straight the app (if installed) without going to safari, or open the itunes store.

Thanks in advance.